# Reference: Reduction of degrees of freedom in hamiltonian mechanics

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

Where can I find a reference which explains clearly when and how a constant of motion in a hamiltonian dynamical system reduces the number of degrees of freedom?

I am looking for something not very abstract.

Comment: the best possible help perhaps is Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems by Marion and Thornton.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what level of "not abstract" you are looking for but I found [this set of lecture notes](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/mechanics.pdf) very helpful as an introduction and for basic understanding. Section 2.7 onwards in it discusses constants of motion.

The classical references would be Abraham and Marsden (Foundations of Mechanics) and Marsden and Ratiu (Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry).

Comment: Abraham and Marsden represent exactly the kind of "abstraction" I am trying to avoid :) I am looking for a condition on the $r$ constants of motion of a system that provide a reduction of the phase space of $2r$ dimensions.